# How can I configure Linux to reopen my SSH tunnels after the connection has been restored?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I am currently working with some SSH tunnels configured. Many times when I loose connection to the Internet or hibernate my laptop, I need to reconfigure the tunnels (i.e., do `killall ssh` and then set up the tunnels once again).

What is the best way to automate it?

Comment: How does the system know the connection is restored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like autossh (Automatically restart SSH sessions and tunnels) could be something for you:
http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/

To keep tunnels alive, and to administrate them in general.

Should be on most distros base repos, so just use one of the following:

```
apt-get install autossh # deb
pacman -S autossh # arch
yum install autossh # rhel
```